# Case - Origin field not available for SOQL

Tags: soql, case

I am unable to query against this field.

[image]

Even a simple SOQL like below is not working.

Can someone tell me why ?

SELECT ID,Origin FROM Case

[image]

Comment: What does field-level security say? Maybe your Profile is not allowed to see the field? Are you by any chance on different license type (say "Platform" license)? Can you see Cases (& that field) normally in the web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to run this in my DEV ORG so there is nothing wrong is your SOQL.

You should check the field level accessibility of Origin field.